# Given a curve over $\mathbb{P}^1$ how can I determine the monodromy around a ramification point?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, riemann-surfaces, covering-spaces

Given a smooth curve of the form
$$
f(y) - g(x)
$$
over $\mathbb{A}^1_x$ with a smooth compactification $C \to \mathbb{P}^1$, how can I determine the monodromy of the points of the fibers? Are there any general tools which will allow me to do this?

Comment: The keys to this question are contained in https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~osserman/rfg/290W/branched-covers.pdf